# How to check if an action name is already taken in a large Redux-app?

Tags: redux

So in the [redux counter example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/counter), they dispatch the following action:

```
onIncrement={() => store.dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' })}
```

But now let's say my app becomes large. Then how do I know which action names are already taken? One way I could think of is to prefix the action with the name of the data it's modifying, so here

```
onIncrement={() => store.dispatch({ type: 'COUNTER_INCREMENT' })}
```

Another way would be to use `typescript` and define a union type

```
type reduxActions = 'COUNTER_INCREMENT' | 'COUNTER_DECREMENT' | ...
```

So what's the community approach for this?

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR**: *Creating a file containing action types, and only that, is one of the solutions that are commonly used.*

Usually, it isn't too much of a problem if your code isn't a mess - well structured Redux apps have their actions / action creators kept in a separate folder, so checking if an action name is already taken should be a breeze.

To further prevent such problems with checking the unique-ness of an action name, you can export all of your action names to a file like `constants/actionTypes.js`.

Then, just export all of your action types.

```
export const increment = 'INCREMENT';
export const decrement = 'DECREMENT';
```

And import them later.

```
import { increment, decrement } from '../constants/actionTypes';
// or
import * as actionTypes from '../constants/actionTypes';
```

Now, if you'd try to redeclare a const with an action type name in the `constants/actionTypes.js` file, JavaScript would throw an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'constName' has already been declared` error - this makes such flaws really easy to spot.

Simple as that.

Comment: Not sure this addresses the question, i.e. two action types with the same name.

Comment: Well, you wouldn't be able to redeclare a const with the same name - JavaScript would throw an error if you'd declare a duplicate action type in your `constants/actionTypes.js` - this solves the OP's problem. Thanks for the remark, I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** I am the main contributer on [redux-subspace](https://github.com/ioof-holdings/redux-subspace).

I created this library to solve this very problem ([among other things](https://github.com/ioof-holdings/redux-subspace#what-it-does)).  It can [automatically namespace actions](https://github.com/ioof-holdings/redux-subspace#namespacing) that are dispatched from within a subspace so you can break your app up into logical sections (you are probabaly already doing this with your react components) and use the action names that make sense, without having to worry about cross talk from other parts of your large application.

```
<SubspaceProvider mapState={(state) => state}, namespace='counter'>
    <Counter />
</SubspaceProvider>
```

This way, the counter can continue to use `INCREMENT` and `DECREMENT` as can a different component (e.g. a `Timer` might also have a `DECREMENT` action) and both will be blissfully unaware of the other.

```
<SubspaceProvider mapState={(state) => state}, namespace='counter'>
    <Counter />
</SubspaceProvider>
<SubspaceProvider mapState={(state) => state}, namespace='timer'>
    <Timer />
</SubspaceProvider>
```

In fact, using redux-subspace, you can even drop multiple counters down on the same page without an issue. (Note: in this example you would need to change how the components [map their state](https://github.com/ioof-holdings/redux-subspace#in-sub-component) slightly)

```
<SubspaceProvider mapState={(state) => state.counter1}, namespace='counter1'>
    <Counter />
</SubspaceProvider>
<SubspaceProvider mapState={(state) => state.counter2}, namespace='counter2'>
    <Counter />
</SubspaceProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at the [redux-action-namespacer](https://github.com/joetidee/redux-action-namespacer) package.